# What happens when you cast an integer array into a char array

Tags: c, casting

I am confused about how this casting works, as my codes show below, an array of 1 2 3 4 5 will be cast into an char array of 1 '\0'. How does this work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main(){
  int array1[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  int array2[SIZE];
  char* array = (char*)array1;
  int i = 0;
  while(array[i] != '\0'){
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not cast the array, but a pointer to the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do here is called *type punning* and frowned-upon. [**edit:** adding Olaf's comment here: This is because the *casting* in your code is happening on the pointer, not on the data it points to.] From what you describe, you are on a little-endian architecture -- assuming it is 32bit, an `int` of 1 would take 4 bytes (32 bits) and represented like this:

```
{ 1, 0, 0, 0 }
```

So your whole array, interpreted as a series of bytes, looks like

```
{ 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, ... }
```

Note this really depends on your implementation and architecture, so just don't do *type punning*. That's the reason why the standard declares accessing a stored value through a pointer of a different type than the declared one *undefined behaviour*. (or, in this case, as type-punning to `char *` is an exception for allowing some necessary use cases, *implementation-defined behaviour* -- you still get different readings on different environments)

Comment: I don't think your method of representing bytes in an int is accurate or informative. What does {1, 0, 0, 0} mean? Just write out the hex value...

Comment: I'm talking about bytes, so this is pretty clear. hex is just another way to write the content than decimal. If you really want to go down to the machine level, try binary and see how readable this will be.

Comment: There's no undefined behaviour with the type punning here. It's perfectly legal to access any object through a character pointer.

Comment: I thought type punning to a `char*` was an exception to UB rule here

Comment: right, it's `char *`, overlooked that. Still the result what you get when reading the individual bytes is implementation-defined. Updating the answer, thanks.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I know what you were going for, my point is that nobody ever uses that notation so it's going to confuse people. Moreover, it's not a good way of displaying the bytes. Yes, *obviously* hex is another representation of a decimal number. Have you ever asked yourself why people use hex at all? It's because the hex number clearly indicates what bytes are in memory because a byte is represented by 2 hex digits. What does a byte translate to in decimal? There's no pattern...that's why everyone uses hex and why you had to invent an arbitrary way to indicate the bytes in the integer.

Comment: @Decave, not an "invention", just regular C syntax and therefore valid in a lot of other languages, too. In my opinion, hex notation would just confuse here. I use hex notation a lot and for me it's appropriate when there's a meaning behind the individual bits (e.g. IO registers), still allowing for an abbreviated representation. I don't consider it approrpiate here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen what is an IO register?

Comment: @Decave a register of some peripheral hardware with for example indiviudal bits controlling functions / modes of that hardware -- typically just mapped into regular address space on a von-neumann architecture, but might be in a special address space on a harvard-architecture...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah you meant hardware registers for buses, gotcha. Well, I disagree that it would confuse -- I personally think it's important to explicitly show how the bytes are laid out in memory, and I think hex is the best way to do that. Clearly not everyone agrees as your answer is upvoted and accepted, but I still stand by my claim.

Comment: @Decave taking into account that the C standard doesn't guarantee *anything* (well, nearly) about representation, not even the position of a sign bit, I prefer not to do this. For showing endianness, only the position of individual bytes is relevant. Although a representation shuffling the bits around would be quite insane, standard C would allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

The result is **implementation-defined**. It depends on the [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) on your machine; in case of x86, it's little-endianess.

`array` is a pointer to `array1`. As your machine is, apparently, little-endian (I guess x86), `array1` internally looks like this, assuming `sizeof(int)` equals `4`:

```
0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x02 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x03 | ...
```

So, as you see, the first `char`'s value is `0x01`, a `0x00` follows. Therefore the result.

Comment: No, that's *little endian* -- and using a *bitwise or* operator doesn't really nail it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Of course your right about the endianess but interpreting the vertical lines as `or` operators is a bit far-fetched, IMO.

Comment: @cad, as this is about C, I'd just avoid such confusion altogether ... having bitwise or with some values written in hex is something you could see quite often in e.g. system or embedded C code, that's why I commented on it ;)

Comment: And if the machine was Big-endian, then there won't be any output as the array is stored as `0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x00 | 0x02 | ...`, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy Right, buddy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of int's size is 4 bytes, but char's size is 1 byte. In this case when you cast you char to int (1 byte to 4) you will get 4 chars from 1 int.
Let's try

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 5

int main(){
int array1[SIZE] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int array2[SIZE];
char* array = (char*)array1;
int i = 0;
while(array[i] != '\0'){
  printf("%d ", array[i]);
  i=i+4;
}
}
```

Comment: Note the OPs code will exhibit the same result on 64bit little-endian. 32bit was just an assumption in my answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: Isn't this UB when `sizeof(int)` is 4? I mean, the loop will access invalid memory locations past the array, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy, yep, there should be added break, you right