# What does int* ip = (int *)p mean?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char p[5] = "ABCD"; 
    int* ip = (int *)p;
    printf("%d \n", *(ip + 0)); // 1145258561 
    printf("%d \n", ip); // 6422016
}
```

Could anybody please explain to me the output of this program?

Comment: it's a cast, and that cast actually invokes undefined behavior. Please read a book first. [What does `(int*) &var` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28522618/995714), [`int num = *(int *)number;` What does this do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4170249/995714), [Is typecasting a `char*` to `int*` undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45303282/995714)

Comment: casting from `char*` to `int*` is prohibited, but the reverse (`int*` -> `char*`) is allowed though: [What happens when you cast an integer array into a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32539591/995714)

Comment: @Dmitry [It ***is*** undefined behavior in this code.  Full stop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)  The ***only*** safe way to convert a `char *` pointer to an `int *` pointer is if the value started as an `int *` pointer in the first place.,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you cast the `char[4]`, `p`, into an `int*` and initialize `ip` with the result:

```
    int* ip = (int *)p;
```

Here you dereference `ip`, which, since it's an `int*` means that it will read `sizeof(int)` bytes to form an `int` from the address `ip` points at:

```
    printf("%d \n", *(ip + 0)); // 1145258561
```

Since `int`s are often 4 bytes, it will often seem to work, but it violates the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/12149471) and results in *undefined behavior*. Also, if an `int` is 8 bytes, the program would have *undefined behavior* since it would then read outside the `char[4]`.

Here you print the value of `ip` as an `int`, but it is a pointer, so again, the program will have *undefined behavior*. Also, a pointer is often 8 bytes so it will likely cause *undefined behavior* for that reason too.

```
    printf("%d \n", ip); // 6422016
```

To properly print pointers, use `%p` and cast the pointer to `void*`:

```
    printf("%p\n", (void*) ip);
```